# Error CS1001 (Identifier expected)

Tags: c#, identifier, method-signature

I'm new to programming and am taking a C# class. I am getting compiler error CS1001 when I try to write this program.

I read the Compiler Error description (link below), but I'm really not getting it. What am I doing wrong?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b839hwk4.aspx

Here is my source code:

```
using System;
public class InputMethodDemoTwo
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      int first, second;
      InputMethod(out first, out second); 
      Console.WriteLine("After InputMethod first is {0}", first);
      Console.WriteLine("and second is {0}", second);
   }
   public static void InputMethod(out first, out second) 
   // The error is citing the line above this note.
   {
      one = DataEntry("first"); 
      two = DataEntry("second");
   }
      public static void DataEntry(out int one, out int two)
      {
         string s1, s2;
         Console.Write("Enter first integer ");
         s1 = Console.ReadLine();
         Console.Write("Enter second integer ");
         s2 = Console.ReadLine();
         one = Convert.ToInt32(s1);
         two = Convert.ToInt32(s2);
      }
}
```

According to the instructions, I'm supposed to have a method b (InputData) which pulls statements from method c (DataEntry)... Here are the instructions:

> The InputMethod()in the InputMethodDemo program in Figure 6-24 contains repetitive
>   code that prompts the user and retrieves integer values. Rewrite the program so the
>   InputMethod()calls another method to do the work. The rewritten InputMethod()
>   will need to contain only two statements:
>
> one = DataEntry("first");
>
> two = DataEntry("second");
>
> Save the new program as InputMethodDemo2.cs."
>
> The InputMethodDemo they are referring to is the same program, except that it calls only one method (the InputMethod) instead of two.

The text I referred to above is "Microsoft® Visual C#® 2008, An Introduction to Object-Oriented Programming, 3e, Joyce Farrell"

Any advice/ help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what you are expected to do:

```
using System;

public class InputMethodDemoTwo
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        int first, second;

        InputMethod(out first, out second);
        Console.WriteLine("After InputMethod first is {0}", first);
        Console.WriteLine("and second is {0}", second);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void InputMethod(out int first, out int second)
    //Data type was missing here
    {
        first = DataEntry("first");
        second = DataEntry("second");
    }

    public static int DataEntry(string method)
    //Parameter to DataEntry should be string
    {
        int result = 0;
        if (method.Equals("first"))
        {
            Console.Write("Enter first integer ");
            Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result);

        }
        else if (method.Equals("second"))
        {
            Console.Write("Enter second integer ");
            Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: That takes care of this week's homework.  Available next week?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
public static void InputMethod(out first, out second)
{
  one = DataEntry("first");     
  two = DataEntry("second");
}
```

to

```
public static void InputMethod(out DataEntry first, out DataEntry second)
{
  first = DataEntry("first"); 
  second = DataEntry("second");
}
```

You haven't provided the type of the arguments. Also, your arguments are called first and second, not one and two.